# Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'some View' and '...'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I get this error when I’m trying to ternary the `navigationBarItems` to have various views:

> Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'some View' and 'ProfileImageBarButton'

```
@State var searchTapped: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Text("lol")
            
   --> here i get the error .navigationBarItems(leading: searchTapped ? backButton : ProfileImageBarButton(showMenu: $showMenu))
        .navigationBarTitle(Text(""), displayMode: .inline)
    }.overlay(searchTextField)
}

private var backButton: some View {
    Image(systemName: "arrow.left")
        .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
        .onTapGesture {
            self.searchTapped = false
        }
}
```

This is `ProfileImageBarButton`:

```
struct ProfileImageBarButton: View {
    @Binding var showMenu: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: UserDefaults.standard.getProfileImage()!)
            .resizable()
            .renderingMode(.original)
            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
            .clipShape(Circle())
            .onTapGesture {
                self.showMenu.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: As per the error `backButton` is an `Image` which is different to `ProfileImageBarButton`. You will need to cast both options `as View` to satisfy the compiler.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The error is telling you that, in an expression:

```swift
condition ? true_result : false_result
```

both `true_result` and `false_result` need to have the same type.

There are multiple ways to overcome this, here are two:

```swift
.navigationBarItems(leading: searchTapped ? AnyView(backButton) : AnyView(ProfileImageBarButton(showMenu: $showMenu)))
```

or

```swift
.navigationBarItems(leading: barItems())

...

func barItems() -> some View {
    return Group {
        if searchTapped {
            backButton
        } else {
            ProfileImageBarButton(showMenu: $showMenu)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: btw. why has it to be the same type when the function expects any type of View?

Comment: The function accepts any view (generic), and so the compiler defers for later, finding out what's the actual concrete type. However, in the case of your example, the compiler cannot do it, because you have two different concrete types. That is just my guess.

Answer (score 19):

You can also use `@ViewBuilder` which allows you to put different views in its body:

```
.navigationBarItems(leading: barItems)
```

```
@ViewBuilder
var barItems: some View {
    if searchTapped {
        backButton
    } else {
        ProfileImageBarButton(showMenu: $showMenu)
    }
}
```